# Replace last character in string, removing 0 to the right

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this expression

```
let acc = "000000000009882275759";
```

And i want return that expression

```
let acc = "988227575-9";
```

I am trying this, but without success

```
console.log(acc.replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/.$/, "-$1")); // 988227575-$1
```

Comment: What language is this for? Please tag accordingly

Comment: To use `$1` in replacement you need to capture something.

Comment: We're does the `-9` comes from in the second code-block? Is it the number of leading 0's?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCFqH.png - would be a Python version. Not sure where -9 came from.

Comment: What should happen if the string is `000000000009` and what if the string is already `9882275759`

Comment: Will the characters always be numbers?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just use one time replace() instead of two. You could try following regex.

```
^0+(\d+)(\d$)
```

Details:

- `^0+`: captures all zeros. String starts with 0. **Through regex, a string found that is not grouped is automatically deleted.**
- `(\d+)`: Group2: after zero, captures all numbers
- `(\d$)`: Group3: captures the last number of account string

Result:

```js
let acc = "000000000009882275759";
result = acc.replace(/^0+(\d+)(\d$)/, "$1-$2");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log("0000000000098820275759".replace(/^0*/, '').replace(/(?=\d$)/, '-'));
```

Output: `9882027575-9`

I used a (?=...) (a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) to find the last place next to the last digit and then put `-` in that sspace

Comment: I suggest sticking more to the question instead of trying to assume things about the string that are not given. 1) There is no reason to change `/^0+/` into `/^0*/`, so I would leave it as is. 2) The title of the question is *"Replace last character in string"* it does not specify that those are digits. I suggest using `/(?=.$)/` instead of `/(?=\d$)/`. Sticking closer to the question avoids introducing new elements which can lead to new misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `$1` in `.replace(/.$/, "-$1")` refers to the first capture group. Since you don't have a capture group in your regex it's replaced with the literal `$1`. There are two options.

1. Capture the last character in capture group 1. This is done by adding parentheses around the thing you want to capture. `.replace(/(.)$/, "-$1")`
2. Use `$&` instead of `$1` which refers to the the whole match. `.replace(/.$/, "-$&")`

See the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Description) documentation for details.

```js
const acc = "000000000009882275759";

console.log(acc.replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/(.)$/, "-$1"));
console.log(acc.replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/.$/, "-$&"));
```